# Spark first() taking a very long time

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I was thinking that first() should not take a lot of time(relative to the input size), but it might be that I'm doing something wrong in how it is used. I wasnt to check whether a given value is present, say 'FAIL' in the result column. I want to know if at least one row has a 'FAIL' result column value.

I have this:

```
is_failed = bool(df.select(df["result"]).filter(df["result"].contains("FAIL")).first())
```

Is this an efficient way to go about doing that in Pyspark?

Comment: the `first()` has to run the filter operation first. so, if the data is huge along with skew, it will take time. you could check the performance by removing the filter once.

Comment: If I have say 100 columns, wouldn't it be quicker to filter by the column I'm interedted in and then apply first? 
Result column has only two values, PASS and FAIL.

Comment: I was merely asking you to do a test for first's performance on the data. nothing about the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using first is >5x slower than using isEmpty if you only want to check at least one row is present.

Excusing the Scala, you can prove this out in pyspark as well:

```scala
    var start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    var isEmpty = sparkSession.range(10000000)
      .repartition(100)
      .first() == null
    println(isEmpty)
    var end = System.currentTimeMillis()
    // scalastyle:off
    println(s"first duration = ${end - start}")

    start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    isEmpty = sparkSession.range(10000000)
      .repartition(100)
      .isEmpty
    println(isEmpty)
    end = System.currentTimeMillis()
    // scalastyle:off
    println(s"isEmpty duration = ${end - start}")

    isEmpty = sparkSession.range(10000000)
      .repartition(100)
      .first() == null
    println(isEmpty)
    end = System.currentTimeMillis()
    // scalastyle:off
    println(s"first duration = ${end - start}")

    start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    isEmpty = sparkSession.range(10000000)
      .repartition(100)
      .isEmpty
    println(isEmpty)
    end = System.currentTimeMillis()
    // scalastyle:off
    println(s"isEmpty duration = ${end - start}")
```

The duplication is a poor mans microbenchmark but indicative and quick enough to play around with.  The performance difference will increase with the number of fields used by .first() as .isEmpty does not select any columns:

```
false
first duration = 8784
false
isEmpty duration = 1242
false
first duration = 5034
false
isEmpty duration = 1041
```

Comment: I didn't get the difference between the first two and the last two, to me it looks like first and isEmpty is being tested twice? Anyway I wanted to check for the presence of a particular value, not whether it is empty or not.

Comment: the jvm optimises code as it runs, the first run is never appropriate, real benchmarking does lots of warmup and repeat runs, the above code is definitely not that, just indicative.  Re the particular value - you know that .isEmpty will work when you have a filter right?

Comment: ohhh... I think I finally get it. did you mean I could do .filter(col = 'value').isEmpty instead of first? If yes, that's brilliant!

Comment: correct, but it'd be great if you can comment how it improved perf for your case (or indeed if it didn't).

Comment: Also note that if you want to use the filtered results after testing them you should keep the dataframe as a variable, and possibly even .cache it for best performance (otherwise you risk re-evaluating several times).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using pyspark with Spark 2.4 and it doesn't have isEmpty(). I get this error, 'File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1300, in __getattr__
    "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'isEmpty'

Comment: :< then you're left with upgrading - which you should really do if possible, or having the worse performance I'm afraid.

Comment: Unfortunately that  version upgrade is outside my control. And using the filter(col==="value").first() is casing a Stack overflow error :/

Comment: I'd suggest raising a separate stack on the SOE, that's not related to this question.